# Using Twitter framework to get tweet details

Tags: ios, search, twitter

I am developing an ipad application running in ios 5.1 in which twitter integration has been done. Now i could able to tweet using my application using the twitter.framework. But i want to get the details of the tweet that we made. I used TWRequest in the framework to post a query as

```
-(IBAction)queryButtonTapped:(id)sender{
    TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=indians&rpp=5&with_twitter_user_id=true&result_type=recent"] parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        if([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200){
            NSError *error;
            NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
            UIAlertView *alertView1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Twitter response"
                                                                 message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"response: %@",dict]
                                                                delegate:self
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView1 show];
        }
        else{
            UIAlertView *alertView2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"oops"
                                                                 message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"response: %i, and error is %@",[urlResponse statusCode],error]
                                                                delegate:self
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView2 show];
        }
    }];
}
```

Here i am searching indians tweet that i made.

I got an alert with message as "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active.PLease migrate to API v1.1." Now i want to know what is that 1.1 version. Does it have something to do with Twitter.framework or should i get new twitter.framwork. Or else i need to query in different manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been having the same issue for a month now, see if  [this](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone)  helps. The twitter framework uses api version 1.0 and its has been take down now.